# UIView animation is leaking

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, ipa

In my viewcontroller i am using animation for changing the frame of UIButton and UIView, going from portrait to landscape user can see views growing but problem is animation is leaking everywhere and showing everything coming from different sides.

Here is the code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];
[UIView setanimationDuration:1];
[view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,300)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate more on what "leaking everywhere" means, and does it make a difference if you use block animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:nil animations:^{
    [view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,300)];
}completion:^(BOOL done){
    if (done) {
        NSLog(@"animation complete");
    }
}];
```

According to Apple's documentation:

> In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods.
>   (Recommended)

Comment: i tried the block but still it didn't solve the problem, leaking everywhere means if i show the UIAlertView, its coming from different corners and you see animation when you load a different UIView.

Comment: @Saleem That's interesting, can you provide me more information on the context in which the above code is being called?

Comment: thanks for prompt response, i am calling this in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation. i am checking the orientation and changing the frame of UIViews accordingly.

Comment: This is an iPad application and problem is i have UIView and UIButton of same size and when you chnage the orientation i change the width of both, but UIView moves faster than UIButton so you see small gap between both for like 0.1 second. so i applied the animation, they can move together when i change the frame in landscape, it worked fine but when i select some other row in masterView it shows the animation that view and button are laying down again. Is there anyway that i can move them together without using animation. if i dont use animation the width of button moves faster than uiview.